# Minio Instance configuration

Tags: node-red, minio

Good morning everyone.

I am doing a project where I need the automatic configuration (via msg) of a Minio instance (node-red-contrib-minio-all). I am using the Objects operation node (the operation is a putObject), I am able to send the buckets, object and stream parameters but I have not been able to configure the instance. I need to configure the properties of minio-config node( MinIO host, port, secretKey, accessKey and useSSL).

Does anyone have a reference to this? Greetings Vincent

This is with Node-Red and enter the node programming (minio-config.js) and in theory it should work with msg.host, msg.port, etc. But the truth is that I don't know what will happen because with the parameters of the buckets, objects and operation it works correctly. What doesn't work is the automatic configuration of the Minio instance.

Answer (score 0):

The minio node (node-red-contrib-minio-all) node has a feature to set the parameters of the operation (bucket, filename, ...) dynamically. But as far as i know it does not provide the functionality to change the node configuration dynamically.

NodeRED itself also does not provide a general way to change the node configuration dynamically (https://flows.nodered.org/flow/6fe183c197b3464a1fe4d89744e068ff):

> The configuration of a node is set on node creation, so there is currently (<= 0.15) no general way to change the configuration dynamically.

In the linked post there is also an example of a dynamically modified config of a tcp out node. It requires changes the config of the tcp node and then calls the Admin-API to rederploy that node.

This is rather complex and may cause other problems.